# Calculate distance to the nearest other point in a layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-expression

I would like to calculate the distance to a point's nearest neighbour within the same layer.

I can do

```
distance( closest_point(  $geometry , $geometry ),$geometry)
```

But that includes only the current feature so the result is always 0. I need a way to collect all the features and filter out the current feature or a better approach

I have also tried:

```
distance(closest_point((collect( $geometry , filter:=   $id  IS NOT   attribute( $currentfeature,  $id ))),$geometry ), $geometry )
```

Comment: `overlay_disjoint()` could help, but I can't promise.

Comment: "Returns whether the current feature is spatially disjoint from all the features of a target layer, or an array of expression-based results for the features in the target layer that are disjoint from the current feature." - Returns true or false  - doesn't sound promising

Comment: The NNJoin plugin may be useful.

Comment: @John that would probably work but I am looking for something I can use in an expression ideally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use `overlay_nearest` instead:

```
distance(
  $geometry,
  array_first(
    overlay_nearest(
      '<point_layer_name>',
      $geometry
    )
  )
)
```

The expression engine **does not consider the current geometry** when used **on the same layer**, so no further filtering is required.¹

**Edit:**

If the self-join exclusion doesn't work, get the *second closest feature* instead:

```
distance(
  $geometry,
  array_get(
    overlay_nearest(
      layer := '<point_layer_name>',
      expression := $geometry,
      limit := 2
    ),
    1
  )
)
```

---

¹ tested on `QGIS 3.26.1-Buenos Aires`

Comment: Duh, obvious solution. +1

Comment: Using 3.26.2-Buenos Aires and inserting the layer name I still get a distance of 0

Comment: To test I used a geometry generator to draw a line 1 m north east from point it is reporting the distance to and it is measuring the distance to itself. make_line( 
  $geometry ,
   translate( 
    array_first(
    overlay_nearest(
      'MAXIMA_448b10d9_debf_4945_bafa_6fe735c55e73',
      $geometry))
    
 ,1,1))

Comment: @Sethinacan well, you can always just fetch the second closest feature - see my edit.

Comment: Your suggestion does resolve the self-joint issue, though your expression has a ,1 in the wrong place . I am little concerned that if the self joint  exclusion does start to work then it will pick up the second feature but that is an issue for another day. Thanks.  I will mark the answer as correct assuming you can fix the expression.