# QGIS: Distance to nearest polygon in another filtered layer

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, distance

I have two layers, one that collects data and is made up of some hundreds polygons and another that has polygons for cities/towns/villages and includes the number of inhabitants. In the data collection layer I want to register the distance to the nearest polygon in the inhabitants layer. I filtered the inhabitants layer to be >= 100 / 250 / 500 / 1000 /10000 inhabitants and did a field calculator operation in the data collection layer for each, as follows:

```
distance(
  $geometry,
  array_get(
    overlay_nearest(
      layer := '<Layer_name>,
      expression := $geometry,
      limit := 2
    ),
    1
  )
)
```

I copied that from [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/459031/calculate-distance-to-the-nearest-other-point-in-a-layer-in-qgis). To my understanding, it takes the second closest feature to avoid matches with itself. When I do it this way, I get values that seem to make sense, while getting the closest feature like this

```
distance($geometry, array_first(overlay_nearest(layer:='Lines', expression:=$geometry)))
```

always yields the same result, even though the distance to bigger places usually should be higher. So I want to go with my first code snippet. However, I do not understand the code good enough to be sure that it really takes the closes feature from <Layer_name> and never excludes one of *those*.

[image: Rough layout of the situation]

In the above drawing the collection layer on the left should get different distances of the filtered layer for 100 and 250 inhabitants, then the same for 500 / 1000 as the closest polygon in each case is the one labeled 1000. Then the 100,000 inhabitants polygon is the one furthest away. Can I be sure that the first code snippet never hops over the 100-labeled polygon? The green polygons in the drawing are on a different layer than the black "Collect."-labeled polygon.

Comment: Posting a small subset of your data may help in getting responses. You shouldn't need to get the second closest feature as you're looking for a feature in a different layer (ie different question to the link you posted). Your second query looks OK to me (and works for me on my own data).